# Adding hyperlink in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a `gridview` which displays all a database table with columns `TaskId`, `Title`, `Reward`, `Time Allotted`, `Poster Name`. Although all my `SqlConnection` code is present on another webform which is used to insert data in to database table.

Here is my code on `InsertTask.aspx.cs` page:

```
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTasks", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", txtBody.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reward", txtRewards.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeAllotted", txtTime.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PosterName", txtPoster.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblStatus.Text = "Task Posted Successfully.";
    }
}
```

This inserts task in to database table successfully. So on a new webform which is `default.aspx`, I have a `gridview` which is connected to that database table and shows a list of tasks in the table.

Again, I have not written any code on `default.aspx.cs`.

What I need to do is make `Title` as a hyperlink in the `gridview` which I can click and get on a different page which is in accordance to the rows. Can that be done? Or should I use a button on all rows to get to other pages accordingly. How can that be done?

I have no experience with `gridview`.

Comment: You can use link button within Template field or Use CommandField and Set ButtonType="Link".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement get all data to a dataset or datatable and bind it to gridview. And in default.aspx markup we can convert gridview columns to hyperlink fields in different manners by using `<asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>` in `<Columns>` tag

Here I added two controls one is html hyperlink and other is asp:hyperlink

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvrecords"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Title">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Title", "~/../urpath/{0}") %>' runat="server"/>
<a href ='<%#"page.aspx?TitleID="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"TitleId") %>'> <%#Eval("Title") %>  </a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Action">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a id="A1" runat="server" href='<%#  @"~\Demolink.aspx"+( Eval("Record_ID").ToString()) %>'>
                      <%#Eval("Title ") %> </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can use hyperlink for title. To provide hyper link you can use **TemplateField** as mentioned in below code sample :

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridTask" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="htttp://www.stackoverflow.com"><%#Eval("Title") %> </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Body" HeaderText="Body" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reward" HeaderText="Reward" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Note:** Here I have used stackoverflow site url. instead you can use the url of your page.

Comment: Down voter don't down vote the answer without comment and until you don't have strong reason to down vote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="htttp://www.mydummyurl.com"><%#Eval("Title") %> </a>
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

This should work!

Comment: How your answer differ with SpiderCode's one ?. Please read other answers before posting..!